# Update Widgets in PDF using Podofo

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation, podofo

I am using PdfAnnotation.SetContents to set the value of an annotation.If the annotation is of type FreeText, only then this method correctly works and the value gets displayed on the PDF (using PDF Reader).If the type is Widget, the value gets set as content in pdf dictionary but does not get displayed.Is there a way i could set the value of a widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, In order for the content to get displayed, an Appearance ("AP") Dictionary has to be set.

This could be used for that:

```
void PdfField::CreateFieldAppearance(PdfMemDocument *memDoc, const PdfString &value)
{
  if( !m_pWidget->HasAppearanceStream() )
  {
    PdfRect pageRect;
    PdfPainter painter;

    PoDoFo::PdfRect rect = this->GetWidgetAnnotation()->GetRect();
    unsigned int width = rect.GetWidth();
    unsigned int height = rect.GetHeight();

    PdfRect pdfRect(0, 0, width, height);    

    PdfXObject xObj(pdfRect, memDoc);
    painter.SetPage(&xObj);
    painter.SetClipRect(pdfRect);

    painter.Save();
    painter.SetColor(221.0/255.0, 228.0/255.0, 1.0);

    painter.FillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    painter.Restore();

    // make rotation

    painter.Save();

    /***********************************************************************************/

    // Rotation Logic

    double angle = this->GetPage()->GetRotation();

    if (angle) {
        double radAngle = angle * M_PI / 180;

        int cosA =  (int)cos(radAngle);
        int sinA = (int)sin(radAngle);

        double translateY = rect.GetWidth(); // The View goes out of the bound, sits on top
        painter.SetTransformationMatrix(cosA, sinA, -sinA, cosA, translateY, 0);
    }
    /***********************************************************************************/


    PdfFont *font = memDoc->CreateFont("Helvetica", true, false);
    font->SetFontSize(15);     

    // Do the drawing
    painter.SetFont(font);
    painter.BeginText(10, 5);
    painter.SetStrokeWidth(20);
    painter.AddText(value);
    painter.EndText();

    painter.FinishPage();

    // This is very important. Not only does it disable the editing.
    // Also it does correct the appearance issue on Adobe Readers.
    this->SetReadOnly(true);

    // The Stream Object has to be saved to the annotation
    PoDoFo::PdfDictionary dict;
    dict.AddKey( "N", xObj.GetObject()->Reference() );
    this->GetFieldObject()->GetDictionary().AddKey( "AP", dict );
}

}
```

Comment: Above code is working fine. Can you please tell me how to add image on appearance.@iphonic and @qamar